# CSS. Can't get text closer to image. Help me understand

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a backend developer that is totally lost with CSS. This time I just can't get a text closer to an image. What I need is the text to be right next to the image, I know it must be easy, but I've tried enough.

So this is what I want:

```
               |------|
          Text |Image |
               |------|
```

And this is what I get:

```
               |------|
      Text     |Image |
               |------|
```

I do need to float the image to the right, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/x3kdbgmh/3/) is a fiddle where you can find the code and the result.

This is the code:

```
HTML
<div class = "div_image pull-right">
    <a class = "topic_name" href = "">
    Topic</a>
    <div class = "image image_topic">
        <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

CSS:
.div_image{
  width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.topic_name{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
.image_topic{
  margin-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right
}

.image > img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width:auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is css for "pull right"?

Comment: @Cory OP forgot to mention that the fiddle uses Bootstrap, hence `.pull-right`

Comment: ahh - gotcha - should have known that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is pulled-right, but the text isn't. however, the surrounding div is wider than both... so the text sits where it normally does (on the left) and the image pulls right (right to the edge of the surrounding div).

If you want the text to sit next to the image - it probably should also be pull-right (also remove the absolute positioning).

The following works for me. Notice that I had to make both text and image pull-right... and flip the order of them so that they appear in the correct order when done.

```
<div class="div_image pull-right">
    <div class = "image image_topic pull-right">
        <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
    </div>
    <a class="topic_name pull-right" href = "">Tema</a>
</div>

.div_image{
  width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.topic_name{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.image_topic{
  margin-left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this is being used, but this is how I would do it:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/kator/1/edit

[image]

### CSS / nice and small:

```
.div_image{padding:10px;}
.div_image a {display:inline-block;padding:5px 10px 0 0}
.div_image img {max-width:45px;max-height:45px}
.div_image .image {float:right;}

.clear {clear:both;} /* demo */
```

### HTML -- Same order as OP

```
<div class = "div_image clearfix pull-right">
 <a class = "topic_name" href = ""> Topic</a>
 <div class = "image image_topic">
  <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
 </div>
</div>

<br class="clear">

<div class = "div_image clearfix pull-right">
 <a class = "topic_name" href = ""> Topic goes here what if it's long</a>
 <div class = "image image_topic">
  <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

If you are required to use the wrapper, you can do this:

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/vaduti/1/edit

[image]

### CSS with wrapper

```
.div_image {
    width: 170px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    margin: 10px; /*demo only*/
}

.div_image a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 55px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.div_image img {
    max-width: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
}

.div_image .image {
    float: right;
    margin-left: -45px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both
}

/* demo */

.div_image > div {
    float: right
}
```

### HTML with wrapper and inner div

```
<div class = "div_image clearfix pull-right">
  <div>
 <a class = "topic_name" href = ""> Topic</a>
 <div class = "image image_topic">
  <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem comes from css rule "position: absolute" in .topic_name. When I delete it and add float: right, it rendered properly, except the order of text and image. So after switching the order of top_name and image_topic. It should work as you wish.

```
HTML
<div class = "div_image pull-right">
    <div class = "image image_topic">
        <img src = "http://mybirdie.ca/files/att00052trees-around-the-world.jpg">
    </div>
    <a class = "topic_name" href = "">
    Topic</a>
</div>

CSS:
.div_image{
  width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topic_name{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
.image_topic{
  margin-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right
}

.image > img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width:auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    either reduce the width:
```

`.div_image {
display: inline-block;
height: 150px;
width: 89px;
}

OR

add margin left in the text

.topic_name {
border: 1px solid red;
margin-left: 85px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-top: 12px;
position: absolute;
text-align: right;
}

</pre>`